# /google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/appcfg.py download_app not downloading all project files and folders

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a project deployed on the google app engine .I want to download the source code to my local ubuntu PC to work on and later deploy back on the google app engine.However when i am trying to download using appcfg.py its not downloading the entire project instead only downloading app.yaml , main.py and dispatch.yaml . I am new to google cloud. Please help.

Comment: What are the other files you would expect it to download?